# join multiple csv files in one folder using pandas [MemoryError:]

Tags: python, pandas

I have 5 csv files in one folder, In here I want to join all columns from each csv file into one dataframe. When I only join 2 csv files, it works well, but when I want to join 5 csv files, I faced an error. My code is following below:

```
In [7]:

import pandas
import os
import numpy as np
import glob

path =r'D:/PreprocessingITRC/output/All/'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
for file in allFiles:
    df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(file),index_col=0, header=0)
    dataframe = dataframe.join(df, how='right')

dataframe
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: The error seems pretty obvious, how big are the files?

Comment: Can you explain the relationship between these 5 dfs? are they part of a larger data sample row-wise or column-wise? In which case it may work if you just a list add each df to this list and then call `pd.concat(df_list)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham total size is only 9 KB

Comment: @EdChum average columns each csv file only 3 columns and total number of rows is 38 row (same each file)

Comment: can you share the files?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham oke this [one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w6h891l4twxztfm/fIle.zip?dl=0)

Comment: Your indices are duplicated so basically when performing a right merge it's exponentially finding matches hence why you run out of memory, What is the first column supposed to be? You could just ignore it: `pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(file),index_col=None, header=0)`

Comment: @EdChum I have solved the problem, I remove the [Unnamed] column. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool, I've posted an answer, generally be careful when merging indices or on columns that contain either duplicate values or `NaN` as you will see a large increase in the number of rows

Comment: I've posted an update as I think that seeing as your dfs are equivalent row-wise you should be able to just append to a list and then `concat` them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv files had an unamed index where all the values were `0`, when merging this causes the duplicate matching to explode exponentially as it's finding every combination of matches:

bluetooth.csv:

```
,Bluetooth
0,9.0
0,21.0
0,14.0
```

GPS.cav:

```
,place,distance
0,3.0,15362.9633071
0,3.0,15813.7281014
0,1.0,15360.0862917
```

As you've specified in your code that this column should be treated as the index, your merging goes iffy.

I'd specify that this column is not the index so that it creates a new one for you:

```
pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(file),index_col=None, header=0
```

**EDIT**

Also looking at what you're doing I think you don't need to merge, just `concat` a list of dfs:

```
path =r'D:/PreprocessingITRC/output/All/'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
dataframes = []
for file in allFiles:
    df = pandas.read_csv(os.path.join(file), index_col=None, header=0)
    df.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True)
    dataframes.append(df)
merged = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
```

Comment: I have tried using this technique to merge last csv about 10+ each of size more than 10mb and I am getting this error `pandas.io.common.CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.`